# jQuery scrolling to anchor -> but prevent bumping to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

I made a smooth scroll on my page, but when scrolling to the last anchor on my page the scroll just bumps radically to the bottom, because the content of my last div is not enough to fill the whole page and so the nice easing is gone.

The function tries to put the anchor to the top of the page, but the div is to short.

Is there some way that I can prevent this? Is there some way the tell the function not to bump to the bottom?

Many many thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/5FwcT/4/

```
$('.submenu a').bind('click',function(event){
var $anchor = $(this);

$('html, body').stop().animate({
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-1}, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');

event.preventDefault();


});
```

Example here:

[image]

Comment: can you make a demo of this in jsfiddle? probably easier to see the issue here. usually jumping is fixed with `event.preventDefault();`, but i suspect that may not be the case here

Answer (score 1):

The snippet here is incomplete when compared to the jsfiddle example provided.

Still, I'd try this:

```
$('.submenu a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $($(this).attr('href'));
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $anchor.offset().top-1}, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');
    });
});
```

If there is no more scrolling to do, the scrollTop will do its work up until the moment there is no more scroll that can be done because the document is over. There is no more scroll that can be done, so if the content height (probably you are scrolling `document.body` here) is too small in comparison with the `window.innerHeight` the scrollbar will be really small, and there will not be enough scrolling to do to bring the element to the very top of the viewport.

I have something similar with a fixed sidebar sub-navigation. See here:

```
$(".side-nav li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $($(this).attr("href"));
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
    },1500);
});
```

This will scroll the target into view with a margin on top because I am using a fixed navbar at the very top of the pages. I am also pinning down the subnavigation into place (css:: `position:fixed`) when it is about to be scrolled out of view.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5FwcT/5/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.submenu a').bind('click', function (event) { 
        var $anchor = $(this);
        if ($anchor.attr('href') != "#webservers") { // if href does not = #webservers
            $('html, body').animate({ // animate as usual 
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 1
            }, 3000, 'easeInOutExpo');
        }
        if ($anchor.attr('href') == "#webservers") { // if href does = #webservers
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('body').height() - $(window).height() // animate to the body's height minus the window's height, basically the bottom of the page less the height of the window.
            }, 3000, 'easeInOutExpo');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much! I'll award the bounty as soon as possible (in 4 hours).

Comment: Paul, a question. This works for me regardless, and I didn't know about the plugin used as well, so great stuff, thanks. But suppose there's more content under that last anchor, just not enough to fill the whole page, is there a way to make it scroll to the maximum, without "bumping" to the bottom of the page, as the initial question asked ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it works as intended. Somehow it was scrolling so the bottom of the div was hitting the bottom of the screen. Idk what happened, but you're example works perfectly. Sorry about that.